# Civ 6 "Play Now" change difficulty

Tags: civilization-6

The "Play Now" button starts a new game with Prince difficulty.

Is there a way to change the difficulty setting on that button?

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/340412628175535808/

This might solve your problem. Tell me if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. There is a "difficulty" setting in the .INI file,  but it doesn't appear to do anything.